# Microsoft Push Notification Service capacity

Tags: push-notification, windows-phone, mpns

Does anybody know the limits of using the MPNS? I need to know specifically if I can send to MPNS millions of notifications to unique devices (if I ever had) almost all at once (seconds) and how will the MPNS handle it? is it no problem? will MPNS handle the notifications as soon as it can? would the MPNS block my service?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only limit I saw mentioned on MSDN is this :

> Authenticated web
>   services do not have a daily limit on the number of push notifications
>   they can send. Unauthenticated web services, on the other hand, are
>   throttled at a rate of 500 push notifications per subscription per
>   day. For more info, see Setting up an authenticated web service to
>   send push notifications for Windows Phone.

It's a limit per device per day, and it exists only if you don't setup an authenticated web service.

They don't mention a limit on the number of unique devices.

Comment: Yes it looks there is no limitations, I'll see if I can just throw thousands of fake messages to push channels containing the same base url but different id and see if they don't block me at some point

Comment: @Keoz If you use such fake notification channels you'll always get 404 response codes. They might block you in this case (since they might see it as a DDoS atack), but even if they do, it doesn't mean that they would block you when you send thousands of messages to real devices.

Comment: ok yes it could be, but I'm not really interested in they processing the push but to not ban me forever :)